# При конвертации аудио из m3u8 с помощью FFmpeg меняется размер пакетов из-за чего нарушается целостность файла

Tags: ffmpeg, конвертация

Я использую команду

```
ffmpeg -i https://cs1-72v4.vkuseraudio.net/s/v1/ac/HXP1EQFWu_mYzDFAJm-qFq0i2P1b13wP86bD4BlsdukciZ8IlJskwHVFVqIaTJhDu_38XJr4iAeMyEOPpo9C2T7DvDXZjBSADBeqdwE6Sfimsxp-s4NL1GkA4wz0Xp7J2tmbWaCl4uPjiDiA6Ai1k2uX5dCW7gG3P-unjkBY5o_jYAc/index.m3u8 -vcodec copy -c copy  -flush_packets 0 -crf 50 /storage/emulated/0/i.mp3
```

Но файл на выходе длины меньшей, чем аудиозапись должна быть и при воспроизведении слышно, как пропускаются куски песни

Во время конвертации в логах меня насторожили сообщения

```
[mpegts @ 0xf3117400] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0xf3117400] changing packet size to 188
```

Я не силён в составлении ffmpeg команд, хотя читал документацию.

Прошу помочь мне

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед `-i` надо поставить `-http_persistent false`. Команда будет выглядеть так:

```
-http_persistent false -i [ссылка] -vcodec copy -c copy [путь]\файл.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

Написал программу для конвертации
https://disk.yandex.ru/d/x2rGG3tXAJ8ApA
как работает написано тут:
https://github.com/JustChasti/m3u8-to-mp3-converter/blob/master/readme.md